# C++ One Header Multiple Sources

Tags: c++, header, include

I have a large class `Foo`<sup>1</sup>:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void apples1();
    void apples2();
    void apples3();

    void oranges1();
    void oranges2();
    void oranges3();
}
```

Splitting the class is not an option<sup>2</sup>, but the `foo.cpp` file has grown rather large. Are there any major design flaws to keeping the definition of the class in `foo.h` and splitting the implementation of the functions into `foo_apples.cpp` and `foo_oranges.cpp`.

The goal here is purely readability and organization for myself and other developers working on the system that includes this class.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Large" means some 4000 lines, not machine-generated.
<sup>2</sup>Why? Well, `apples` and `oranges` are actually categories of algorithms that operate on graphs but use each other quite extensively. They can be separated but due to the research nature of the work, I'm constantly rewiring the way each algorithm works which I found for me does not (in the early stage) jive well with the classic OOP principles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any major design flaws to keeping the definition of the class in foo.h and splitting the implementation of the functions into foo_apples.cpp and foo_oranges.cpp.

to pick nits: Are there any major design flaws to keeping the *declaration* of the class in foo.h and splitting the *definitions* of the *methods* into foo_apples.cpp and foo_oranges.cpp.

1) apples and oranges may use the same private programs. an example of this would be implementation found in an anonymous namespace.

in that case, one requirement would be to ensure your static data is not multiply defined. inline functions are not really a problem if they do not use static data (although their definitions may be multiply exported).

to overcome those problems, you may then be inclined to utilise storage in the class -- which could introduce dependencies by increasing of data/types which would have otherwise been hidden. in either event, it can increase complexity or force you to write your program differently.

2) it increases complexity of static initialization.

3) it increases compile times

the alternative i use (which btw many devs detest) in really large programs is to create a collection of *exported local headers*. these headers are visible only to the package/library. in your example, it can be illustrated by creating the following headers: `Foo.static.exported.hpp` (if needed) + `Foo.private.exported.hpp` (if needed) + `Foo.apples.exported.hpp` + `Foo.oranges.exported.hpp`.

then you would write Foo.cpp like so:

```
#include "DEPENDENCIES.hpp"
#include "Foo.static.exported.hpp" /* if needed */
#include "Foo.private.exported.hpp" /* if needed */
#include "Foo.apples.exported.hpp"
#include "Foo.oranges.exported.hpp"

/* no definitions here */
```

you can easily adjust how those files are divided based on your needs. if you write your programs using c++ conventions, there are rarely collisions across huge TUs. if you write like a C programmer (lots of globals, preprocessor abuse, low warning levels and free declarations), then this approach will expose a lot of issues you probably won't care to correct.

Answer (score 4):

From a technical standpoint, there is no penalty to doing this at all, but I have never seen it done in practice.  This is simply a issue of style, and in that spirit, if it helps you to better read the class, then you would be doing yourself a disservice by not using multiple source files.

edit:  Adding to that though, are you physically scrolling through your source, like, with your middle mouse wheel?  As someone else already mentioned, IDE's almost universally let you right click on a function declaration, and go to the definition.  And even if that's not the case for your IDE, and you use notepad or something, it will at *least* have ctrl+f.  I would be lost without find and replace.

Comment: I use Emacs, so yes, I rarely scroll through the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define the class in one header file and split the function implementations accross multiple source files. It is not usually the common practice but yes it will work and there will be no overheads.

If the aim to do so, is just plain readability, then perhaps it is not a good idea to do so, because it is not so common practice to have class function definitions accross multipls source files and might just confuse someone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't see any reasons to split implementation because other developers should work with the interface, but not the implementation.

Also any normal IDE provide an easy ability to jump from function declaration to it's defenition. So there is no reason to search the function implementations manually.