# C++ class for managing the access to database

Tags: c++, database, class

The question is more a *Best way of doing* question than a real problem.

## Context and what I'm doing

I have an application that must access to the database. Therefore I have a class `DatabaseManager` that is called every time I need to access the database and which does for instance:

```
DatabaseManager *db = new DatabaseManager;
std::vector<Element> elementVector = db->getAElementsById(id);
```

And you the same for all insert, update or remove requests.

## What eventually happened...

...is that my file has already 1200 lines and is growing with every new feature.

## The question

So how do *pretty* people do ?

- One header several splitted files? ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170232/c-one-header-multiple-sources) told that it's not a good idea)
- Splitting the class in several class? The databaseManager is one class, it would be a nonsense...
- Is there any other option? (I'm not familiar with the notion of namespace, maybe is it a way?)

I read also other post but didn't find either the good question to ask google, or people answering my question.

Comment: I understand that your problem is the size and complexity of the databaseManager source file, correct ?

Comment: Yes. I use an IDE so it's not so awful, but it could become a pain.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this question.

Comment: OK.  And your database manager grows, because for every new type of object you want to store/rretrieve you need to create new funtions, isn't it ?

Comment: Pretty people leave ugly database library-building to others and use one of the many that are already out there (e.g., [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/)). There's also a whole general area of development (ORMs) that deal with the same sort of problem you seem to have here.

Comment: yes exactly. So my question is about how do people normally do.

Comment: They build something much more generic for the database management interface itself. Some do that with ugly stringly-typed interfaces. Others do it with various forms of code generation (either templates or generating normal source code).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ok, so you mean that it's somehow something that everyone has to face if not using ORMs (It's true I read once a part of Doctrine's source.... Uhhhh) --

Comment: @RSahu: I don't really see the difference of the two forums and I'm used to go on this one.

Comment: @ochurlaud, the other site is better for software architecture and design, which is your question. This site is better for specific programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my database module split into more than one file.  For example, one file handles insertions, another file handles extractions and a third handles searches.

Mine is actually more complex, but the practice should be to split up the code into separate themed files, preferably no more than 300 LOC (Lines Of Code).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I chose for now is the following (because I was too lazy to reconstruct new classes and so on) : I splitted the class in several cpp files

```
// DatabaseManager.h

class DatabaseManager
{

//// Getters - in DatabaseManager_getters.cpp
public:
    // Movies
    Movie getOneMovieById(const int id);
    QList<Movie> getAllMovies(const QString fieldOrder = "title");
    ....

private:
    // Other functions for getters
    Movie hydrateMovie(QSqlQuery &query);

//// Inserts - in DatabaseManager_insert.cpp
public:
    bool insertNewMovie(Movie &movie);
    ....

private:
    bool insertNewTag(Tag &tag);
    ....

//// Updates - in DatabaseManager_update.cpp
public:
    bool updateMovie(Movie &movie);
    ....

//// Delete - in DatabaseManager_delete.cpp
public:
    bool deleteMovie(Movie &movie);

private:
    bool deletePeople(const People &people);

};
```

And obviously the .cpp files are following what announced. It's easier for me to find where a function is and to maintain the code.

Another time, I'll think twice if it's not more relevant to follow the advices you gave.

Thx again !